# How to use AWS Elastic Beanstalk multi docker containers?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to create an environment in Elastic Beanstalk with two containers (backend & frontend).

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.0'

services:

    my_api:
        image: "850977987151.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-api:latest"
        environment:
            ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Staging
        ports:
            - "9901:80"
        volumes:
            - "./Logs:/app/Data/Logs"

    my_app:
        image: "850977987151.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-app:latest"
        ports:
            - "80:80"
```

The publication worked normally, but my frontend (angular) application is not able to consume the api on port 9901.

Error:

> localhost:9901/UserConfiguration/GetAll:1 Failed to load resource:
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

**If I access my EC2 instance and run:**

```
curl http://localhost:9901/UserConfiguration/GetAll
```

Works normally!

**CorsOrigins config on appsettings.json:**

```
"ServerRootAddress": "http://localhost:9901",
    "ClientRootAddress": "http://myappqa-env.eba-xasnmn7n.sa-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com",
    "CorsOrigins": "http://myappqa-env.eba-xasnmn7n.sa-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com,http://localhost"
  }
```

**Angular appconfig.json:**

```
"remoteServiceBaseUrl": "http://localhost:9901"
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**

Even if I allow any origin in my API, as the code below, I still have the same error.

```
services.AddCors(
    options => options.AddPolicy(
        _defaultCorsPolicyName,
        builder => builder
            //.WithOrigins(
            //    // App:CorsOrigins in appsettings.json can contain more than one address separated by comma.
            //    _appConfiguration["App:CorsOrigins"]
            //        .Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            //        .Select(o => o.RemovePostFix("/"))
            //        .ToArray()
            //)
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials()
    )
);
```

Comment: [ stupid comment ] I have an app I use for tests that has a similar architecture (Angular UI + App Server) [here](https://github.com/mreferre/yelb/). I have a [compose file](https://github.com/mreferre/yelb/blob/master/deployments/platformdeployment/Docker/docker-compose.yaml) that works fine with Beanstalk. One thing it's not clear to me is... is the angular/JS code that is calling `localhost`? If that's the case how can it work if it's run client side (which would explain why if you ssh into the instance and run curl against localhost it works).

Comment: Perhaps completely unrelated but for completeness, the way it works in my app is that the client code connects to `window.location.href` (which represents the URL from where the client code has been downloaded). My nginx serving the JS code than proxies the API call to the API server. [See diagram](https://github.com/mreferre/yelb/blob/master/images/yelb-architecture.png)

Comment: @mreferre your comment wasn't stupid at all, it was exactly that. What I needed was to expose my API as well and use that address in the frontend. If you want to put it as an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: Oh nice. I turned these comments into an answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an app I use for tests that has a similar architecture (Angular UI + App Server) [here](https://github.com/mreferre/yelb/). I have a [compose file](https://github.com/mreferre/yelb/blob/master/deployments/platformdeployment/Docker/docker-compose.yaml) that works fine with Beanstalk. One thing it's not clear to me is... is the angular/JS code that is calling localhost? If that's the case how can it work if it's run client side (which would explain why if you ssh into the instance and run curl against localhost it works).

Perhaps completely unrelated but for completeness, the way it works in my app is that the client code connects to `window.location.href` (which represents the URL from where the client code has been downloaded). My nginx serving the JS code than proxies the API call to the API server. See diagram:[image: architecture].

Answer (score 1):

Since the services are running in a docker network, then you should connect from one service to another using the service name and container port, like "my_api:80". Port 9901 is the port on the container host (EC2 instance). The services themselves are running in a different network that is the docker network.

Comment: Do I need to change something in the docker-compose file? I still have the same error.

Comment: Update the .json files accordingly. Let them use `my_api:80` .

The docker-compose file looks okay to me.

Comment: I will review the file, but I have already made the change and continued with the error.

Comment: Did not work :(